# Performing assertions in Junit 5 @AfterAll

Tags: java, unit-testing, kotlin, junit5

I am trying to add a feature to a mocking framework to have a test class fail when there is a method that has been stubbed but never actually invoked, i.e. either the test contains too much stubbing or the tested code didn't follow the intended path.

I can already do the check, and I was planning on doing it in the `@AfterAll` method implemented by a JUnit extension, something like this:

```
@ExtendWith(MyExtension::class)
class TestClass {

    @Test
    fun myTest() {
        // stub a function
        // run some test code
    }
}
```

```
class MyExtension : AfterAllCallback {
    override fun afterAll(context: ExtensionContext) {
        if (not all stubbed methods have been called) {
            throw AssertionError("Something")
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `AssertionError` being thrown in the `afterAll` body does not make the tests fail.

It kind of makes sense to me, since `afterAll` is expected to be executed after all the tests, when the tests result has already been computed, but I was wondering if there was a way to have a test class failure triggered after all tests have been executed.

Comment: Interestig thing: when I launch your example as a single test class in Intellij, I see a test pass. If I execute the entire package (which only contains this one test) or when I execute from maven, I see a test failure as expected.

Comment: @JockX that's right, I didn't notice it. If I run the single class in IntelliJ Idea, I see the single tests pass. If I run `gradle build` on the whole project, the build fails.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an specific issue with the IDEA version you've used, as I can confirm IJ 2023.1.1 behaves as expected:

[image]